# Filter val variable without changing its declaration Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code:

```
selectedMedias.filter { !File(it.path).exists() }
```

**info: Filter returns another object that is filtered wrt the given callback**

The problem is here `selectedMedias` is declared as val. I don't want to change the declaration to make the code

```
selectedMedias = selectedMedias.filter { !File(it.path).exists() }
```

How can I filter a `val` variable without changing its declaration?

I cant reassign selectedMedias since selectedMedias is an ArrayList for an adapter, that's why I can't reassign it

Comment: Is `selectedMedias` a property of some class?

Comment: its an ArrayList for an adapter, thats why I can't reassign it

Comment: And are you sure you have to change the `selectedMedias` content? Maybe a custom `get` method `val selectedMedias get() = field.filter { ... }` or a backing property `val filteredSelectedMedias get() = selectedMedias.filter { ... }` are what could help you solve the problem.

Comment: yes I have to change it, both your solutions seem like a way-around. However, this filtering operation rarely occurs so setting a get() would be an overkill for other parts of the code that access selectedMedias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter a list in-place (assuming* it's a `MutableList` such as an `ArrayList`) with `removeIf()`:

```
val selectedMedias = mutableListOf(File(a), File(b))
selectedMedias.removeIf{ File(it.path).exists() }
```

Note that the predicate is inverted: it should return `true` to remove the item, and `false` to keep it.  (There doesn't seem to be a corresponding `keepIf()`, unfortunately, as that would work more similarly to `filter()`.  But you could easily write one if you wanted!)

(* If the list isn't mutable, and isn't a `var`, then there's no way to change it, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to modify a `val` property of type `ArrayList<T>`.

The instance is immutable because of `val`, but you can modify the inner values as usual:

```
val selectedMedias = ArrayList<T>(/*init value*/)

selectedMedias.apply {
   val newValues = this.filter { !File(it.path).exists() }
   clear()
   addAll(newValues)
}
```